# Some questions regarding how to disable auto restarting after Windows 11 installed an update?

Tags: windows, windows-11, windows-update, group-policy

I want Windows 11 to automatically download and install updates in the background, just let me choose when to restart my laptop, even outside of active hours. So, I looked up some solutions and they told me to enable:

```
legacy policies -> no auto-restart with logged on users for scheduled automatic updates and installations
```

and

```
manage end user experience -> configure automatic updates
```

under

```
group policy editor -> local computer policy -> computer configuration -> administrative templates -> windows components -> windows update
```

Will this make it what I want it to be? or should I toggle some other settings on/off? I made the group policy change yesterday (before the update downloads), but it still restarted to update when it's scheduled time.

(Btw I choose number 3 in the configure automatic updates policy, idk if it's correct, I am on build 22621)

Appreciate your help.

Comment: Once updates have been and have run, you must restart within 2 weeks. No way around that, and you must restart on Windows terms.

Comment: Does the 2 weeks deadline start counting down when I clicked on download and install in the settings? Is there any way to postpone within the 2 weeks period other than schedule restart in the settings app? Also, does that mean `no auto-restart with logged on users for scheduled automatic updates installations` policy only applies for under 2 weeks? thank you

Comment: Is there any way to postpone within the 2 weeks period other than schedule restart in the settings app?   ........  No.  That is the update limit.

Comment: I am not sure what the issue is. Windows Updates occur 2nd Tuesday of each month. Just plan for them

Comment: yeah the problem is most of the time something is still running (like video encoding), and it auto restarts in the night which I won't know cus I am sleeping

Comment: Do these tasks take *two weeks*?

Comment: Updates do not take 2 weeks. You need to sort out the App time.